# Lua registry: it is shared by threads?

Tags: lua

Lua provides a ["registry"](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.5) "that can be used by any C code to store whatever Lua values it needs to store". And threads "shares with the original thread its global environment", as said [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_newthread). But I can not find any place where it says if it shares the register.

So that's basically my question: if the threads are derived from the same original state, do they share the table accessible at LUA_REGISTRYINDEX?

Comment: All threads share the same VM, hence, its registry.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks... Have you used a shared registry between threads? Does it work?

Comment: Lua "threads" are not usual OS threads.  They are for [coroutines](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CoroutinesTutorial) only.  Lua VM works in single-threaded mode (only one CPU core is used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lua registry is part of the `lua_State*`, thus anything using or contained within a given Lua_state (Such as Lua threads: Co-routines) will also share its Registry.

*Lua Threads* (co-routines) are part of the `lua_State*` they were created from, and thus share the same Registry.

*OS Threads* will access whatever Registry is associated with the `lua_State*` passed to `lua_getfield(...)` *(et al.)*.
Bare in mind that Lua's only assurance with respect to OS threading is that the Lua CAPI is reentrant and stores all its values in the `lua_State*`; its up to you properly manage the state to avoid simultaneous access and corruption.